# How do I set up a theme inside embedded spring boot keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

currently using keycloak embedded in spring boot.
I created themes under resources to create a custom theme.
It was registered in keycloak-server.json as follows.

```
"theme": {
    "staticMaxAge": "${keycloak.theme.staticMaxAge:2592000}",
    "cacheTemplates": "${keycloak.theme.cacheTemplates:true}",
    "cacheThemes": "${keycloak.theme.cacheThemes:true}",
    "folder": {
        "dir": "src/main/resources/themes"
    }
}
```

Although this works fine in the local environment. It doesn't work when run with jar file.
The cause seems to be not finding the path properly. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same issue. I deployed my app to AWS ElasticBeanstalk, but I was unable to setup Keycloak to locate the themes folder correctly.

I tried every variation I could think of:

- under the /tmp folder
- /BOOT-INF
- and simply /themes

I also explored the EBS EC2 instance to find the right folder (I've found the folder, but it didn't work as well), so far no luck.

I ended up uploading the themes folder separately to the home folder, manually changing the keycloak-server.json file as follows:

```
"folder": { "dir": "/home/ec2-user/themes" }
```

I couldn't manage though to have this value taken dynamically from the application.property file.

Answer (score 0):

Create `keycloak-themes.json` file inside `src/main/resources/META-INF` and add below content.

```json
{
  "themes": [{
    "name" : "custom",
    "types": [ "login", "account", "welcome" ]
  }]
}
```

compile using maven and run the jar. `java -jar <jar name>`.

For more information refer this
https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/themes.html